# IDE error with string template specialization (solved in comments)

Tags: c++

I practice C++ on codingame.com.

If I can't do that, what is the point of templates ?

```cpp
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
string rjust(const int padding, const T value, const char c=' '){
    string v = to_string(value);
    return string(max(0, padding - int(v.length())), c) + v;
}
template <>
string rjust<string>(const int padding, const string value, const char c) {
    return string(max(0, padding - int(value.length())), c) + value;
}
```

The IDE/Compiler don't want I do `rjust(0, "abcd")` because of `std::to_string(template_as_string)` in `rjust()`, even with template specialization.

Comment: `"abcd"` is not a std::string

Comment: Also, to nitpick, this is **explicit** specialization.

Comment: Thank you @Mat, `ljust(0, string("abcd"))` worked. @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica I thought explicit was the usage like that `ljust<string>(0, s)`. It seems I need some learning. What is the magical string type ? Should I remove this question ?

Comment: Magical string type? If you're refering to the type of a string literal: that's `char const[N]` with `N` being the number of characters in the literal + 1 (for the terminating 0). Since the second parameter is not a reference type, this type decays to a pointer in your case, so `ljust(0, "abcd")` calls `ljust<char const*>`.